# How to enable unsafe legacy in cpanel?

Tags: laravel, ssl, openssl, cpanel, whm

I have purchased the recharge API from the third-party API service. The code is working fine on the local environment but when I deployed the code on the server.

It gave me a timeout error and later on, it started showing me could not connect errorr.

I mailed their team so they told me that this is your server issue. You need to enable Unsafe-Legacy. I googled it but did not find the answer to this que.